# Android - OR condition SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

In My application I am setting 3 alarms for one medicine.. I want to get the medicine name for any one of them..
The query I am firing-

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT " + MedName+" FROM " + TABLE_LABELS +" WHERE "+Alarm1+ "=? OR "+Alarm2+ "=? OR "+Alarm3+ "=?";
```

This returns the name only for alarm1. The names for alarm2 and alarm3 are empty.
What am I missing?

Comment: What's Alarm1, Alarm2 and Alarm3?
It should be everytime the same string which contains the column-name?!

Comment: What are the values and how are you binding the selection args? How are you executing the query?

Comment: Alarm1,Alarm2,Alarm3 are Strings.. stores time as "12:01:00"..

Comment: Your query is **wrong**, then... It has to be: `WHERE Field1 = ? OR ... ` and you should pass Alarm1(2, 3) in a **string array**, in the same order of the **?** s.

Comment: And maybe you should consider ORMlite in future, it helps to avoid such sutiations, because you don't have to make quriers manually, in case you'll think about it http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_1.html#Getting-Started

Comment: Did you place `?` value only one time? There should be one value for each `?` in you query.

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT " + MedName + " FROM " + TABLE_LABELS +" WHERE " + COL_NAME + "=" + Alarm1 + " OR " + COL_NAME + "=" + Alarm2 + " OR " + COL_NAME + "=" +  Alarm3;
```

Comment: I have stored the time values in database and I am comparing it to the current time, passing current time as argument.  getMedName(currentTime)... so med name has to check if the current time is in any on the columns Alarm1,Alarm2 or Alarm3

Comment: Do you store them as timestamps or strings?